# Duplicar números randômicos

Tags: java, android

Eu criei uma class que nele contém um método que gera um numero randomico de 0 á 61... no meu `Fragment` eu instanciei dentro do meu evento de `button`... Minha dúvida é, como que eu faço para colocar a quantidade de vezes que ele vai gerar para mim. Por exemplo, tenho um `spinner` com as opções 1,2,3 então escolho o 2, ao clicar no botao ele tem que gerar para mim:

1º = 25
2º= 50

**isso tudo ao mesmo tempo**

como que eu faria? pois se eu criar cada método para a quantidade de vezes fica difícil, pois imagina se o usuário quer 100 vezes, ai complica. Então como que eu faria isso, não tenho a minima ideia, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Código:

```
public void geraSix(){
    MegaSenaController numberRandom = new MegaSenaController();
    numberRandom.megaSena();
    String groupFirst = numberRandom.getPrimary();
    groupText.setText(groupFirst);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Não ficou claro o que os métodos criados por você fazem exatamente, mas seguindo a sua lógica você deve armazenar os valores em um `List` e depois mostrá-los. Ex:

```
MegaSenaController numberRandom = new MegaSenaController();
int qntNumeros = (int) spinner.getSelectedItem();
List<Integer> numeros = new ArrayList();

for (int aux=0 ; aux<=qntNumeros ; aux++) {
    numberRandom.megaSena();
    numeros.add(numberRandom.getPrimary());  
}
```

Isso faz com que os números aleatórios sejam armazenados em `numeros`. Depois é só mostrá-los.

Comment: Adptei algumas coisas, mas não conseguir fazer a multiplicação...

Comment: Multiplicação? Você refere-se à criação dos números aleatórios, certo? Já tentou printar o retorno dos métodos `megaSena()` e `getPrimary()` para ver se estão corretos? Tente postar o código deles na sua pergunta também.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que um loop for resolva:

```
for (var i = 0, max = max/*neste max voce deve pegar o valor que o usuario quer*/; i < max; i++) {
    //gera um numero aleatorio
}
```